# Averaging control group conditions into new output column. Output column contains the associated control average values

Tags: r, dataframe

Not new but still a beginner to R.

This is a snippet of my `data` (numbers randomised so the `Average` columns are not correct in this example).

```
> head(data)
                  1          2          3   Average   HKAverage        dC
Neg CNTRL        NA         NA         NA        NA          NA        NA
NEG CNTRL        NA         NA         NA        NA  0.80393767        NA
POS CNTRL 0.1836139 0.11392904 0.02925255 0.1089318  0.72559250 0.6165367
WT 1      0.5091585 0.15929057 0.51686195 0.3951037  0.26582395 0.5877941
WT 2      0.1924527 0.05267426 0.77929719 0.3414747  0.48798007 0.2600975
WT AA 1   0.2525962 0.97503047 0.62913683 0.6189212  0.03930599 0.9048247
> tail(data)
                  1         2         3   Average   HKAverage         dC
T AB 4    0.3425330 0.1698632 0.3100509 0.2741490   0.2312321 0.39589730
T C 1     0.8170886 0.8202081 0.1487331 0.5953433   0.1268834 0.99938496
T C 2     0.4374555 0.1926919 0.2847973 0.3049816   0.8647057 0.00970199
T C 3     0.3194017 0.2683773 0.8150882 0.4676224   0.8750478 0.73646663
T C 4     0.1091098 0.1547485 0.9696392 0.4111658   0.9897441 0.18335950
Pos CNTRL        NA        NA        NA        NA          NA         NA
```

I'm doing some calculations with these values and the outputs are generated as a new column.
I'm running this before running any calculations:

```
data <- as.data.frame(input.data)
data[data == "Undetermined"] <- NA
data[] <- sapply(data, as.numeric)
```

Ignoring the 4 CNTRL rows (I should probably just remove them then!) there are WT... and T... for the same conditions. These conditions are repeated 2 or 4 times (hence WT 1, WT 2, T 1, T 2, etc.).
I want to make a new column that contains the average of a WT condition. In the rows for the T conditions I want the same WT averages to show up there.

This would be an example of my output: (Av meaning average)

```
> head(newdata)
          X        X1         X2         X3   Average  HKAverage        dC ControlAv
1 Neg CNTRL        NA         NA         NA        NA         NA        NA        NA
2 NEG CNTRL        NA         NA         NA        NA 0.80393767        NA        NA
3 POS CNTRL 0.1836139 0.11392904 0.02925255 0.1089318 0.72559250 0.6165367        NA
4      WT 1 0.5091585 0.15929057 0.51686195 0.3951037 0.26582395 0.5877941   WT1:2Av
5      WT 2 0.1924527 0.05267426 0.77929719 0.3414747 0.48798007 0.2600975   WT1:2Av
6   WT AA 1 0.2525962 0.97503047 0.62913683 0.6189212 0.03930599 0.9048247 WTAA1:4Av
> tail(newdata)
        X        X1        X2          X3   Average HKAverage        dC ControlAv
10   T V1 0.4568928 0.5566606 0.610042142 0.5411985 0.8372219 0.9200497   WT1:2Av
11   T V2 0.8633715 0.3191596 0.483468638 0.5553332 0.8860817 0.9486309   WT1:2Av
12 T AA 1 0.1587924 0.2986826 0.005692643 0.1543892 0.1064064 0.7750263 WTAA1:4Av
13 T AA 2 0.3665066 0.9289861 0.143083833 0.4795255 0.4543861 0.9992564 WTAA1:4Av
14 T AA 3 0.5580805 0.4041877 0.411612593 0.4579603 0.8457465 0.9380688 WTAA1:4Av
15 T AA 4 0.8149501 0.1642240 0.229479382 0.4028845 0.7638992 0.6026836 WTAA1:4Av
```

I'm currently trying to use the `within()` function but not finding success:

```
> data$wt.av <- within(data, mean(dC["WT 1" & "WT 2"]))
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

My dataframe is numeric but the `rownames` are obviously not.

`aggregate()` doesn't work in this case because the `rownames` do not match

Comment: Provide an minimum reproducible example of your data (`dput` for example). How do you calculate the `ControlAv` column?

Comment: @RobertoT Apologies. I do this using sapply.```data[] <- sapply(data, as.numeric)
data$Average <- rowMeans(data, na.rm=TRUE)
data[data == "NaN"] <- NA```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using a very long winded method that is not very elegant. But it's done!

I took apart the data frame...

```
dat.V <- data[4:5, ]
```

for each control group. Then used `cbind` to put these averages onto the non-control group data frames. Then used `bind_rows` to bring all of this back together into one data frame.